# How to show SMS number and restrict to write certain number of SMS in text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to allow user to write maximum 6 SMS into my web application using a TextArea. Here, each SMS length is 160 character and I want to show it as Current SMS Number/6. When user reaches on 6th SMS then the application should not allow them to write for the 7th SMS.
I've written the Javascript to get the remaining character number and to show it into a box. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        else
            countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
</script>


<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="150px" onkeyup="showPrevMsg(this.value);"
onkeydown="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 160);" onfocus="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 160);" onblur="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 160);" placeholder="Please enter the body of your message here" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>


<input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="remLen" size="3" maxlength="3" value="160" />
characters left
```

But with the above I can only get the remaining characters out of 160. I also need to show how many SMS has been written out of 6 for example 1/6 and restrict user on 6th SMS. Please help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: update `countfield = field.value.length;` to show the length of the field instead of subtracting from `maxlimit`. For the 2nd part does the user post back to create the 1st SMS ?

Comment: no user does not post back to create the 1st SMS.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something to solve my own problem. Here I'm posting my solution in case it may help some one else.

I've created this javascript function to count the part of the messages. As I'm not that familiar with Javascript or Jquery so I've done this in this way (may be it can be done in simple way).

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
        function msgCounter(txtField, msgCount) {
            if (txtField.value.length <= 160) {
                msgCount.value = "1/6";
            }
            else if (txtField.value.length > 160 && txtField.value.length < 321) {
                msgCount.value = "2/6";
            }
            else if (txtField.value.length > 320 && txtField.value.length < 481) {
                msgCount.value = "3/6";
            }
            else if (txtField.value.length > 480 && txtField.value.length < 641) {
                msgCount.value = "4/6";
            }
            else if (txtField.value.length > 640 && txtField.value.length < 801) {
                msgCount.value = "5/6";
            }
            else if (txtField.value.length > 801 && txtField.value.length < 961) {
                msgCount.value = "6/6";
            }
            else {
                //alert("Maximum SMS number reached!");
            }
        }
</script>
```

From asp textbox I'm calling the both javascript functions to achieve the goal like this:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="150px" onkeyup="showPrevMsg(this.value);"onkeydown="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 960);msgCounter(this,this.form.msgNumCount);" onfocus="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 960);msgCounter(this,this.form.msgNumCount);" onblur="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 960);msgCounter(this,this.form.msgNumCount);" placeholder="Please enter the body of your message here" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

Thanks everyone for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've one aspx page where you can find your solution. You can directly use this.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="JSDemo.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("<%=txtMessage.ClientID%>").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
                if ($(this).val().length <= 160) {
                    $('#CharacterCount').html((160 - $(this).val().length) + ' characters left');
                    $('#SMSCount').html('1/6');
                } else if ($(this).val().length > 160 && $(this).val().length <= 320) {
                    $('#CharacterCount').html((320 - $(this).val().length) + ' characters left');
                    $('#SMSCount').html('2/6');
                } else if ($(this).val().length > 320 && $(this).val().length <= 480) {
                    $('#CharacterCount').html((480 - $(this).val().length) + ' characters left');
                    $('#SMSCount').html('3/6');
                } else if ($(this).val().length > 480 && $(this).val().length <= 640) {
                    $('#CharacterCount').html((640 - $(this).val().length) + ' characters left');
                    $('#SMSCount').html('4/6');
                } else if ($(this).val().length > 640 && $(this).val().length <= 800) {
                    $('#CharacterCount').html((800 - $(this).val().length) + ' characters left');
                    $('#SMSCount').html('5/6');
                } else if ($(this).val().length > 800 && $(this).val().length <= 960) {
                    $('#CharacterCount').html((960 - $(this).val().length) + ' characters left');
                    $('#SMSCount').html('6/6');
                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#CharacterCount').html('0 characters left');
                    $('#SMSCount').html('6/6');
                    alert('6 SMS has been completed!');
                    //
                    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,960));
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="150px" placeholder="Please enter the body of your message here" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            <span id="CharacterCount"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="SMSCount"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```